# C# Selenium MoveToElement not working as expected (moving several elements from one ul)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am learning how to use the Actions class at the moment and I have a little trouble with the moving of elements, I am not sure if the problem is in my code or in the webpage that I am using to test. Basicly I want to perform several reorders,

```
Drag1 -> Drag2
Drag2 -> Drag1
Drag3 -> Drag4
Drag4 -> Drag2
```

So in the end the order of the elements should look like:

```
Drag1
Drag4
Drag2
Drag3
Drag5
```

Instead what happens is

```
Drag1 -> Drag2
Drag2 -> Drag1
Drag1 -> Drag2
Drag2 -> Drag1
```

The first 2 operations are just getting repeated and it does not touch Drag3 and Drag4 at all....

Here is my code:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

            string[] elementIDs =
            {
                "Drag1",
                "Drag2",
                "Drag3",
                "Drag4",
                "Drag5"
            };

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://testing.todvachev.com/draganddrop/draganddrop.html");

            IWebElement[] elements =
            {
                driver.FindElement(By.Id(elementIDs[0])),
                driver.FindElement(By.Id(elementIDs[1])),
                driver.FindElement(By.Id(elementIDs[2])),
                driver.FindElement(By.Id(elementIDs[3])),
                driver.FindElement(By.Id(elementIDs[4]))
            };

            MoveElementFromTo(actions, elements[0], elements[1], 0, 5);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            MoveElementFromTo(actions, elements[1], elements[0], 0, 5);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            MoveElementFromTo(actions, elements[2], elements[3], 0, 5);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            MoveElementFromTo(actions, elements[3], elements[1], 0, -5);

            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            driver.Quit();
        }

        static void MoveElementFromTo(Actions actions, IWebElement from, IWebElement to, int x, int y)
        {
            actions.ClickAndHold(from)
                   .MoveToElement(to)
                   .MoveByOffset(x, y)
                   .Release()
                   .Build().Perform();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is related with how moveByOffset. You already have moveToElement, is it not working when not followed by moveByOffset? or you could try put offset in MoveToElement instead

Comment: I tried putting offset inside the MoveToElement it gets even more screwed up, and I need to add an offset because if you place one of the Drag elements on top of another they will not get switched it needs to go a little lower (or higher depending on how you're moving) than the element to get them switched. The problem is that on my third MoveElementFromTo() it doesnt touch Drag3 and Drag4 at all

Comment: What happens if you use a new `Actions` class instance instead of trying to reuse one? There is very little overhead in creating instances of that class.

Comment: Thanks Jim that solved it! I changed all invocations of the method to be with new Actions(driver) and it works perfectly!
MoveElementFromTo(new Actions(driver), elements[0], elements[1], 0, 5);

Answer (score 0):

Solution as recommended by JimEvans is to just pass a new Actions class every time

```
MoveElementFromTo(new Actions(driver), elements[0], elements[1], 0, 5);
Thread.Sleep(2000);
MoveElementFromTo(new Actions(driver), elements[1], elements[0], 0, 5);
Thread.Sleep(2000);
MoveElementFromTo(new Actions(driver), elements[2], elements[3], 0, 5);
Thread.Sleep(2000);
MoveElementFromTo(new Actions(driver), elements[3], elements[1], 0, -5);
```